# Launch Activity in parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-activity, google-gdk

I would like to launch an activity(TargetActivity) all the way back from some activity(MainOptionActivity) so that if the user press the back button from the TargetActivity, it goes back to the MainOptionActivity.

Right now its doing the following

```
SplashScreenActivity -> MainOptionActivity -> SomeActivity -> ... -> SomeService -> TargetActivity
```

But I want to do this, which would discards every activities/services after MainOptionActivity

```
SplashScreenActivity -> MainOptionActivity -> TargetActivity
```

Thanks!

P.S
The application is running at API 15, parentActivityName is not support

Comment: Please confirm: in MainOptionActivity, you launch SomeActivity, then some other activities, then service which starts TargetActivity? `all the way back from some activity" - what does it mean exactly? Does MainOptionActivity launch your TargetActivity?

Comment: Yes thats what I meant, I want my MainOptionActivity to launch my targetActivity so that When the user closes/press the back button on TargetActivity, they will land right back on the MainOptionActivity

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the parent of the activity from the manifest like this:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".activities.TargetActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainOptionActivity" >
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.MainOptionActivity" />
 </activity>
```

UPDATE:

I know it is not the better way, but how about overriding the call of the back button?

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onKeyDown");
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TargetActivity.class);
                    MainOptionActivity.this.finish();
                    startActivity(i);   
            }
        else
            {
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Great answer but the application is running at API15 which parentActivityName is not support. Should have mention that before, my bad.

Comment: compile it with a Higher API, but put the minSDK to lower than API, it should work. I'm running that code in an app that has this:  android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" and works fine in Froyo, GB and above.

Comment: I cant change the compiler cause this is a glass application. I have to use the GDK compiler and their current version is 15.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this :

for each activity that you don't want to go back to when you press the back button add this bit of code to the intent you use to call the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
contactIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

This flag tells your activity to not keep it's history in the activities stack.